# byte offset in reading binary data file with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I am using a teensy microcontroller to collect some data and storing it as a binary data file with the following data record format:

```c
struct data_t {
  uint32_t time;
  uint32_t test1;
  uint32_t test2;  
};
```

Then I'm trying to read the data with the following python code

```python
dt = np.dtype([('a', '<u4'), ('b', '<u4'), ('c', '<u4')])
data = np.fromfile(file, dtype=dt)
```

The first two lines of data should look like this:

```python
(925,     1,   2)
(1025,     1,   2)
```

But the first two lines look like this:

```python
(   42,  925,     1)
(    2,  1025,     1)
```

Where did the 42 come from? The data is written using a circulating buffer, and that 42 seems to appear at the beginning of every buffer. Is the 42 some kind of header? How do I read this data properly?

-- edit --

Here is the full output from numpy:

```html
array([(  42,  925,  1), (   2, 1025,  1), (   2, 1125,  1),
       (   2, 1225,  1), (   2, 1325,  1), (   2, 1425,  1),
       (   2, 1525,  1), (   2, 1625,  1), (   2, 1725,  1),
       (   2, 1825,  1), (   2, 1925,  1), (   2, 2025,  1),
       (   2, 2125,  1), (   2, 2225,  1), (   2, 2325,  1),
       (   2, 2425,  1), (   2, 2525,  1), (   2, 2625,  1),
       (   2, 2725,  1), (   2, 2825,  1), (   2, 2925,  1),
       (   2, 3025,  1), (   2, 3125,  1), (   2, 3225,  1),
       (   2, 3325,  1), (   2, 3425,  1), (   2, 3525,  1),
       (   2, 3625,  1), (   2, 3725,  1), (   2, 3825,  1),
       (   2, 3925,  1), (   2, 4025,  1), (   2, 4125,  1),
       (   2, 4225,  1), (   2, 4325,  1), (   2, 4425,  1),
       (   2, 4525,  1), (   2, 4625,  1), (   2, 4725,  1),
       (   2, 4825,  1), (   2, 4925,  1), (   2, 5025,  1),
       (   2,    0, 42), (5125,    1,  2), (5225,    1,  2),
       (5325,    1,  2), (5425,    1,  2), (5525,    1,  2),
       (5625,    1,  2), (5725,    1,  2), (5825,    1,  2),
       (5925,    1,  2), (6025,    1,  2), (6125,    1,  2),
       (6225,    1,  2), (6325,    1,  2), (6425,    1,  2),
       (6525,    1,  2), (6625,    1,  2), (6725,    1,  2),
       (6825,    1,  2), (6925,    1,  2), (7025,    1,  2),
       (7125,    1,  2), (7225,    1,  2), (7325,    1,  2),
       (7425,    1,  2), (7525,    1,  2), (7625,    1,  2),
       (7725,    1,  2), (7825,    1,  2), (7925,    1,  2),
       (8025,    1,  2), (8125,    1,  2), (8225,    1,  2),
       (8325,    1,  2), (8425,    1,  2), (8525,    1,  2),
       (8625,    1,  2), (8725,    1,  2), (8825,    1,  2),
       (8925,    1,  2), (9025,    1,  2), (9125,    1,  2),
       (9225,    1,  2)], dtype=[('a', '<u4'), ('b', '<u4'), ('c', '<u4')])
```

And here is the corresponding full hex dump, note the two lines with the "2a00" are where the "42" appears in the numpy output.

```html
00000000: 2a00 0000 9d03 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  *...............      <-- note the 2a00
00000010: 0104 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 6504 0000  ............e...
00000020: 0100 0000 0200 0000 c904 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000030: 0200 0000 2d05 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....-...........
00000040: 9105 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 f505 0000  ................
00000050: 0100 0000 0200 0000 5906 0000 0100 0000  ........Y.......
00000060: 0200 0000 bd06 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000070: 2107 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 8507 0000  !...............
00000080: 0100 0000 0200 0000 e907 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000090: 0200 0000 4d08 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....M...........
000000a0: b108 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 1509 0000  ................
000000b0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 7909 0000 0100 0000  ........y.......
000000c0: 0200 0000 dd09 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
000000d0: 410a 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 a50a 0000  A...............
000000e0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 090b 0000 0100 0000  ................
000000f0: 0200 0000 6d0b 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....m...........
00000100: d10b 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 350c 0000  ............5...
00000110: 0100 0000 0200 0000 990c 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000120: 0200 0000 fd0c 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000130: 610d 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 c50d 0000  a...............
00000140: 0100 0000 0200 0000 290e 0000 0100 0000  ........).......
00000150: 0200 0000 8d0e 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000160: f10e 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 550f 0000  ............U...
00000170: 0100 0000 0200 0000 b90f 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000180: 0200 0000 1d10 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000190: 8110 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 e510 0000  ................
000001a0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 4911 0000 0100 0000  ........I.......
000001b0: 0200 0000 ad11 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
000001c0: 1112 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 7512 0000  ............u...
000001d0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 d912 0000 0100 0000  ................
000001e0: 0200 0000 3d13 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....=...........
000001f0: a113 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000200: 2a00 0000 0514 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  *...............      <-- note the 2a00
00000210: 6914 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 cd14 0000  i...............
00000220: 0100 0000 0200 0000 3115 0000 0100 0000  ........1.......
00000230: 0200 0000 9515 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000240: f915 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 5d16 0000  ............]...
00000250: 0100 0000 0200 0000 c116 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000260: 0200 0000 2517 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....%...........
00000270: 8917 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 ed17 0000  ................
00000280: 0100 0000 0200 0000 5118 0000 0100 0000  ........Q.......
00000290: 0200 0000 b518 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
000002a0: 1919 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 7d19 0000  ............}...
000002b0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 e119 0000 0100 0000  ................
000002c0: 0200 0000 451a 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....E...........
000002d0: a91a 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 0d1b 0000  ................
000002e0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 711b 0000 0100 0000  ........q.......
000002f0: 0200 0000 d51b 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000300: 391c 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 9d1c 0000  9...............
00000310: 0100 0000 0200 0000 011d 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000320: 0200 0000 651d 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....e...........
00000330: c91d 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 2d1e 0000  ............-...
00000340: 0100 0000 0200 0000 911e 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000350: 0200 0000 f51e 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ................
00000360: 591f 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 bd1f 0000  Y...............
00000370: 0100 0000 0200 0000 2120 0000 0100 0000  ........! ......
00000380: 0200 0000 8520 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ..... ..........
00000390: e920 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 4d21 0000  . ..........M!..
000003a0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 b121 0000 0100 0000  .........!......
000003b0: 0200 0000 1522 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  ....."..........
000003c0: 7922 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 dd22 0000  y"..........."..
000003d0: 0100 0000 0200 0000 4123 0000 0100 0000  ........A#......
000003e0: 0200 0000 a523 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  .....#..........
000003f0: 0924 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000  .$..............
```

Comment: Maybe you can include a hex dump of your file `xxd file | head -3` or go to https://hexed.it/

Comment: Here is the hexdump: (note this was with a slightly different version of the file, in this case the "85" turns out to be "42").


`00000000: 2a00 0000 9d03 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000  *...............

00000010: 0104 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 6504 0000  ............e...

00000020: 0100 0000 0200 0000 c904 0000 0100 0000  ................`

Comment: Ideally, you would click `edit` under your image and paste the hexdump with matching interpretation in there where it can be formatted. Some compilers insert padding in `structs` to ensure alignment, you may need to disable that. You could try writing just 1 struct to file on the teensy and then 10 structs and see how many bytes of data you get in your file. Or you could add an offset of 4 bytes into `np.fromfile()` and see if it is a single lump of padding at start of file but unpadded after that.

Comment: Is the edited post along the lines of what you mean with it being formatted?

Adding the offset of 4 allows the first buffer to be read properly. In principle I could save each buffer to a new file and that would work, but it would be nice to have multiple buffers in a single file. Is there a way to tell fromfile that the offset needs to repeat every XX bytes?

Comment: Yes that's better. I see you've since added a solution which I guess is fine, but given that the data are really there in the file, the real issue must be at the Teensy end...

Comment: I don't think it is so much an issue actually, more of me not understanding how the teensy code was working. It's supposed to be high performance code, so it ends up writing in predefined buffer chunks to minimize reorganization of blocks on the SD card I think. Anyways, thanks for the help - I had spent some time trying to figure out how to open the raw binary file to help debug to no avail until your simple suggestion of using xxd!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is a better way, but using the following nested datatype works:

```
dt = np.dtype([('head', '<u4'), ('buff', [('a', '<u4'), ('b', '<u4'), ('c', '<u4')], (number_of_data_records,)), ('tail', 'i1', number_fill_bytes)])
```

The idea is that I'm reading each block, which includes a 4 byte header, the buffer with (42) records of actual data, and a tail that includes empty filler bytes (defined by the teensy code).

The number of data records is given by the 4 byte header it seems. Can the number of filler bytes be automatically determined?

I put the teensy code, data, and python analysis on github in case it is helpful for anyone: https://github.com/florisvb/data_tutorials/tree/master/TeensyDataLogger